# Access rights and showing/hiding buttons accordingly in XPages (Domino)

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I want to show a button when the current user has Author rights or if the current user is a member of a group, that has those rights.

Now [I found this approach](https://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=determine-if-an-author-can-edit-a-document-alternative).

This is how I tried to implement it, inside the `rendered` property of my button:

```
var cxt = com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NotesContext.getCurrent();
var isEditable = cxt.isDocEditable(currentDocument.getDocument());
return isEditable;
```

In my case `isEditable` is always true.

Can someone tell me if and what I am doing wrong, please?

Thank you in advance.

#### EDIT

It seems I was foolish enough to skip over the `Author` access and tested with `Manager`, `Editor`, `Reader` only.

Big thanks to @Paul Stephen Withers and @Per Henrik Lausten for leading me towards the solution.

For further reference, if someone needs it, here is how I show/hide the edit/hide the save buttons, depending on the read/write mode of the document:

```
// Save button
var showButton = currentDocument.isEditable();
var contxt = com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NotesContext.getCurrent();
var isEditable = contxt.isDocEditable(currentDocument.getDocument());
return (isEditable && showButton);

// Edit button
var showButton = !currentDocument.isEditable();
var contxt = com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NotesContext.getCurrent();
var isEditable = contxt.isDocEditable(currentDocument.getDocument());
return (isEditable && showButton);
```

Comment: What access level does the user have in the acl?

Comment: I've just tested the code with an existing document. If the user has Reader access, it returns false. If the user has Editor access, it returns true. If the user has Author access and is in an Authors field. `currentDocument` will always go to the nearest dominoDocument datasource

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! @PerHenrikLausten I tested with `Manager`, `Editor`, `Reader` and that was the problem - I was foolish enough to skip over the `Author` access. Thank you @Paul Stephen Withers for pointing that out

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I have added an answer based on my comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you test with a user with author access in the ACL of the database.

Your code will always return true for users with editor access.

Answer (score 0):

A different approach is to return the user's accessLevel from the userBean and render the button if the user has EDITOR access or above.  You also need to test for user's with AUTHOR access as well, and for these further test to see if they are in an AUTHORS-TYPE field in the document (the DocAuthor field in example below).

The following code can be used for both cases, and is in the **rendered**  property for an [Edit] button:

```
if (document1.isEditable()){
    return false;
} else {
    var editor = userBean.accessLevel >= lotus.domino.ACL.LEVEL_EDITOR;
    var author = userBean.accessLevel >= lotus.domino.ACL.LEVEL_AUTHOR;
    var isUser = @IsMember(document1.getItemValue("DocAuthor"),userBean.canonicalName);

    if((editor) || (isUser && author)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your input! I will keep this in mind and will test it, when I have time. For now I will go with the approach described above - since I already implemented it that way everywhere.